# matplot program gives unresponsive window when run

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

You'll notice that there is a bunch of missing code, it's for all the games being called from the menu.  I removed it because it is long and not needed for my question.  My issue is only with a particular function, `display_data`.  When I call it from the menu, matplot opens in a new window and just crashes immediately.  I just set up the basic plot below for testing.  Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_data():
    plt.plot([1,2,4],[2,7,9])
    plt.show()

# (6) Save Progress ------------------------------------------------------------

# (7) Load Data ----------------------------------------------------------------

# (8) Quit Game ----------------------------------------------------------------

def quit_game():
    print('\nThank you for playing!')

# Main Menu --------------------------------------------------------------------

def menu():
    calculation_game = print("\nEnter 1 to play 'Calculation'")
    bin_reader = print("Enter 2 to play 'Binary Reader'")
    trifacto = print("Enter 3 to play 'Trifacto'")
    statistics = print("Enter 4 to view your statistics")
    display_data = print("Enter 5 to display data")
    save_game = print("Enter 6 to save your progress")
    load_data = print("Enter 7 to load data")
    quit_game = print("Enter 8 to quit the game")

def main_menu():
    print('Welcome to BrainAge!')
    main_record = []
    user_input = ''
    while user_input != '8':
        menu()
        user_input = input('\nWhat would you like to do? ')
        if user_input == '1':
            calculation_game()
        if user_input == '2':
            binary_reader_game()
        if user_input == '3':
            trifacto_game()
        if user_input == '4':
            display_statistics()
        if user_input == '5':
            display_data()
        if user_input == '8':
            quit_game()

main_menu()
```

Comment: Does it crash or just closes immediately? If crash, show us the error msg, if it just closes, look up the already answered questions about it.

Comment: It just opens a matplot window and it stays white, and stops responding immediately.  No error messages either, just a hard crash.

Comment: What makes you think that matplotlib crashes? For me it *does* crash, but it gives an error about the backend, as it should. If this is the case, try adding `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')` or something similar at the very beginning, before your import. With that change the plot appears as it should. Also, why are you defining all those local variables to `None` in the `menu()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back, try setting this line

```
plt.show()
```

to

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) this overrides the blocking behaviour caused by running `matplotlib.pyplot` in interactive mode, which is known to cause issues in some environments. I believe this only works for the latest version of matplotlib.

Comment: I'll update after I get the real plot set up.  Thank you